Module is said to to not provide export, but it does
As I was refactoring a component (Vue+Quasar), the type Org that I defined in model.ts suddenly raised the error of not being exported in model.ts.
The structure of the tree is
my-app/
├─ src/
│  ├─ components/
│  │  ├─ M2Details.vue
│  │  ├─ model.ts

In M2Details.vue I have
<script setup lang='ts'>
import { Org, OrgDetails} from './model.ts';
(...)
</script>

In model.ts I have
// single organization and its results
export type Org = {
  OrgDetails: OrgDetails
  Org: OrgDetails[]
}

export type OrgDetails = {
  Boss: string
  NrTested: number
  NrFailed: number
}

The only error in the console is
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/components/model.ts' does not provide an export named 'Org' (at M2Details.vue:12:10)

At the same time, vscode is happy with the import (his screenshot is from M2Details.vue, on the line provided above

What could be the reason for this error I have never seen before?

Types don't exist at runtime, so that file does have no real exports.

@jonrsharpe so what could make it possible that in a sibling component such an import of a type from the same file is fine? (and the component renders just fine)

Can't say why it was downvoted, but this shouldn't normally happen, and the question lacks a way to reproduce. This may depend on the setup. .vue and script setup aren't spec compliant and work in undocumented ways.. The error is caused by that import { Org } is preserved in TS output, could be caused by the way script setup processes imports.  It's possible that you won't have this problem with regular script

I should have used import type instead of just import.
Why it works with a simple import on a sibling component importing a type from the same model file - I do not know.

Because of a recent change as far as I know. Foundable in the VueJS changelogs.
